# Setting high-resolution default for KVM/Qemu VM viewers

Tags: virtualization, display-resolution, kvm-virtualization

**TLDR**: All of the existing questions on this topic seem to be about *enabling* 4k display with the Spice virtual display driver.  This question is about making it *sticky*.

**Question**:

I have no problem using my 4K display with Windows 10 guests after increasing the VRAM.

However, both Virt-Manager's builtin viewer and Virt-viewer have a nasty habit of resizing the guest resolution to 1080p every time I open them.  This happens even when running virt-viewer with the full-screen commandline option.

How can I open a fullscreen viewer on my VM that retains the correct VM display resolution... or at least correctly resizes it to 2160p?

Comment: To confirm - the windows setting on the display resolution is changed back from whatever it was to 1080p when you connect - right? In virt-manager there is an option "preferences" -> "Console" -> "Resize guest with window" -  IIRC that is the one meant to tell the guest (through spice) to resize - is that one disabled? Also - for a try - could you disable spice and just enable VNC - that should be unable to carry resize-requests.

Comment: 1. My virt-manager settings: "resize guest with window" is enabled, and "scaling" is off.  It is nevertheless resizing the guest to 1080p, scaled to fill a 2160p display.  Same behaviour in fullscreen and windowed mode.  I must manually adjust the guest resolution after each connection.  Virt-viewer's behaviour is the same.

Comment: 2. Yes, VNC does not resize the guest -- it retains the last-set resolution, even if Spice is enabled.  It appears to be the act of connecting with a spice viewer that is incorrectly resizing.  I suspect that the spice clients themselves are not collecting host resolution correctly.  Any thoughts on where they might be getting it from?

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons virt-viewer, and virt-manager they scale their windows according to gnome settings. If you go to settings -> Displays and change scale to 100%, this problem will go away. But, everything else will be tiny. There got to be a way to tell virt-viewer to ignore scaling that is set by Gnome.

[Here is bug about it](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/spice/spice-gtk/-/issues/29)

If you have your scaling set to 200%, you can scale virt-viewer down, and get the desired result: "virt-viewer -z 50"

Another way to get it working is to start virt-manager with GDK_SCALE=1.

$ GDK_SCALE=1 virt-manager

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use Artix, but I have seen this bug repeated in other threads. It seems to only affect Ubuntu/Debian based distros. I don't have this problem on Artix so it was strange to me seeing these threads about an issue that doesn't exist on other distros, spice display is limited to its virtual drivers so it can't be set to a higher resolution. I'm referring to the actual screen resolution not the physical bounds of the display or vm window, also there is a button next to your view screen that lets you resize it to full screen on the viewer. As for the virtio gpu that you pass over to guest that doesn't use spice drivers. Instead it uses virtio drivers thus, it directly uses the gpu hardware where you get full resolution of your gpu. These virtio drivers need to be downloaded separately from Red Hat, they basically tell Windows its running in a vm. What I think people have confused about qemu full res over the viewer is the concept of vgpu, that is more technology specific it requires discreet graphics. Vgpu can essentially be run full res over spice and virtio, as a bonus vgpu by its very nature can allow up to twelve virtualized gpu's to operate off one graphics card.